# JQuery Find() .val() of dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, find

I am calling a jQuery method with HTML as the parameter.

I then want to check through the HTML for the `input` control with the class of `"LastIdReceived"`. There will always only be one of these.

I then want to find the value that is set to this control (i.e.: the Id of the last control received).

However, the `val()` method is returning `undefined`. I wonder if this is because it is dynamic content and isn't part of the DOM.

If there is a way to get this, please could you share it.

Here is my function:

```
 function AfterLoadingMoreFollowersOpinions(data) {
    var htmlObject = $(data);
    var object = htmlObject.find('.LastIdReceived');
    alert(object.val());  
}
```

---

EDIT:
My Controller is returning a PartialView as the ActionResult, which is then being given to the OnSuccess method of the Ajax call like so:

```
OnSuccess = "AfterLoadingMoreFollowersOpinions(data);"
```

I think it is passing the HTML correctly from this call, as doing an ALERT in the JS for both htmlObject and object are returning [object object] which makes me believe those parts of the JS are working (correct me if I am wrong. I don't know a better way to check).

The HTML that the PartialView renders and passes through (I am assuming) to the JS function is as follows:

```
<div>
<div class="PostedOpinionDiv" id="SkipToOpinion_1002">
<p><b>Id:</b> 1002</p>
<p><b>Author:</b> Joe Shmoe - 8</p>
<p><b>Opinion Subject:</b> Follower Opinion Subject - 2</p>
<p><b>Opinion:</b> Follower Opinion Text - 2</p>
</div>
<input type="hidden" class="LastIdReceived" value="1002" />
</div>
```

As you can see, it's the value of that input that I want to get from my JS function (1002).

Comment: can you give a sample of `data`

Comment: Update the question to include what `data` is

Comment: The `val()` method does not return `undefined`, it returns an empty string if the element has no value, so you're doing something wrong ?

Comment: Using `$(data)`, where `data` is an HTML string should create a DOM element, though (albeit, not one attached to anywhere on the page yet).  It should be able to be searched with `.find()` at that point.  We need to see the data . . .

Comment: @talemyn: Yeah, I didn't see that it was HTML. I thought it was a selector being passed. Still, `.val()` returns `undefined` when no element is found, so if it's there, it's probably at the top where `.find()` won't see it.

Comment: Hi guys, I have edited the initial post to include some extra information. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery's parseHTML() method to work with HTML text as DOM, here's an solution from your given example:

```
//Parse HMTL to DOM and find an item value
function AfterLoadingMoreFollowersOpinions(data) {
    var htmlObject = $.parseHTML(data);
    var object = $(htmlObject).find(".LastIdReceived");

    //alert item value
   alert(object.val());  
}

//Any HTML text
var htmlString = "<div>";
htmlString += "    <div class=\"PostedOpinionDiv\" id=\"SkipToOpinion_1002\">";
htmlString += "        <p><b>Id:</b> 1002</p>";
htmlString += "        <p><b>Author:</b> Joe Shmoe - 8</p>";
htmlString += "        <p><b>Opinion Subject:</b> Follower Opinion Subject - 2</p>";
htmlString += "        <p><b>Opinion:</b> Follower Opinion Text - 2</p>";
htmlString += "   </div>";
htmlString += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"LastIdReceived\" value=\"1002\" />";
htmlString += "</div>";

//Call function and send HTML text
AfterLoadingMoreFollowersOpinions(htmlString);
```

See that working: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZH7v/1/

documentation if you are interested: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/

Comment: Hi there, I copied your sample code, and get this error message from chrome inspector: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'find'"

Comment: that's because this sample code uses Jquery (as you use in your code example) and just console doesn't provide Jquery library. If you want to try this working on console, you have to open a website that uses Jquery, like http://jquery.com/ or even your page that import Jquery library. Ok?

Comment: No, I used the code in my website, which has jquery. And that was the error that came up from the code.

Comment: Okay mate, as you updated your question I updated my answer, could you try again and tell me? Here's code working: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZH7v/1/